# WithEvents is not valid on a local variable declaration

Tags: c#, vb.net, listener

I am trying to port some C# code to VB, and what I think is the VB counterpart of the C# code won't compile but is throwing an error:

> `WithEvents` is not valid on a local variable declaration.

In this code, instances of a custom user control are being added to a subclass of `TableLayout`; the number of controls to be added equals the number of items in the data source; eventhandlers are attached to events declared in the user control:

Here is the original C# code :

```
private void BindUI ()
{
    while (this.Controls.Count < DataSource.DefaultView.Count)
    {
        var uc = new FooControl ();

        uc.BeginEditing += uc_BeginEditing;
        uc.DoUpdate += uc_DoUpdate;
        uc.DoDelete += uc_DoDelete;
        uc.Name = "uc" + this.Controls.Count.ToString ();

        this.Controls.Add (uc);
        this.SetRow (uc, this.Controls.Count - 1);
        this.SetColumn (uc, 0);        
    }
}
```

Here is the counterpart  VB code:

```vb
Private Sub BindUI()
    While Me.Controls.Count < DataSource.DefaultView.Count
        Dim WithEvents uc As New FooControl ' INVALID CODE

        AddHandler uc.BeginEditing, AddressOf uc_BeginEditing
        AddHandler uc.DoUpdate, AddressOf uc_DoUpdate
        AddHandler uc.DoDelete, AddressOf uc_DoDelete
        uc.Name = "uc" + Me.Controls.Count.ToString()

        Me.Controls.Add(uc)
        Me.SetRow(uc, Me.Controls.Count - 1)
        Me.SetColumn(uc, 0)
    End While
End Sub
```

What is the proper way to attach a listener to these instances of `FooControl` in VB.Net ?

Comment: Just remove the `WithEvents`.  You are hooking up the events manually with AddHandler.  WithEvents would be used if you had a persistent variable and wanted let the designer create the events for you.

Comment: _"WithEvents is not valid on a local variable declaration"_ -- well, it's not. Why are you putting it there? What do you expect it to do? If you remove it, what happens that you don't want? Please provide a good [mcve] showing a VB.NET version of the C# code you are trying to port, but which does not behave the way you want, along with a precise description of what the code does and what you want it to do instead.

Comment: Because I was getting an error message "BeginEditing is not an event of Object, and I thought the reason might be that VB required WithEvents in order to expose the event. Turns out that I needed to declare the method parameter "ByRef".

Comment: `...not an event of Object` is a sign of late binding.  Less than ByRef, it needs to be passed `As FooObject`.  Cant be sure since that part isnt shown

Comment: VB.NET requires `WithEvents` only when you are using the [**`Handles` clause.**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6k46st1y.aspx).